# Parse: Posting uploaded file/image to backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a html:

form.html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/"> 
    <input type="file" name="pic" id="imgupload">
</form> 

<script>
document.getElementById("imgupload").onclick = function({myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
   var fileUploadControl = $("#imgupload")[0];
   if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
      var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
      var name = "photo.jpg";

      //how to pass this (parseFile) to server.js? 
      var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
   }
}
</script>
```

and my backend server code using express:

simplified server.js (only server routing):

```
 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //loads the form.html from above. 
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/form.html"); 
 })

 app.post('/', (req, res)=>{
      //once press submit button, will post parseFile to here
      //from here, i will save the parseFile to database. 
      res.status(204).end(); 
 })
```

My goal is to upload an image, then when user press submit, the parseFile variable will be sent to the app.post() in server.js, where the saving occurs.

I've tried multer, where it does not work for Parse.File on the req.file namely:

```
 app.post('/', upload, (req,res)=>{
     //req.file contains the file information
     var file = new Parse.File(name, req.file);

     //save to database via Parse
     file.save(); //example code. 
     res.status(200).success("test code")
 })
```

this code returns TypeError in Parse where Parse.File is unable to create a Parse.File from req.file.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got this to work.

It seems I have to encode the picture in a base64 format and assign the base64 value into an HTML element to be passed into the post method.

Something like:

```
<body>
<input id="inp" type='file' accept=".jpg">
<br>
<img id="img" height="150">
</body>

<input type="hidden" id="base64" name="base64" value=""> 
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" id = "submit">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function readFile() {
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var FR= new FileReader();
      FR.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
      document.getElementById("img").src       = e.target.result;
      //get the base64 encoded string and add it to id=b64. 
      document.getElementById("base64").value = e.target.result;
    }); 

    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
  }
}

document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile);
```

eventually i converted the file into base64 and inserted the base64 value into the element id called base64.

then access the base64 value by calling req.body.base64 in the post method.

Answer (score 0):

The req.file is not the data in a file format that Parse expects (instead its an object in Multer's format) -- so the Parse.File is being called inappropriately. See the Parse SDK here: http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.File.html This explains the datatypes that can be inserted for each function parameter.

req.file.buffer should theoretically work (assuming you get a single file each time from Multer). As you have not constrained multer to work in that way, your code should probably also handle an array of files.

You'll also need to create a string for the filename (name does not seem to be a declared variable in your code).